# ¿Como meto una variable de sesión dentro de un href?

Tags: php, html

¿Como puedo colocar una variable de sesión dentro del a href?, Como se muestra en el ejemplo me manda error de sintaxis en las comillas dentro de los corchetes [''].

```
<?php
            echo
            "<div class='contenedor' id='uno'>
            <a href='c.php?$_SESSION['Materia'] = $row'><img class='icon' src='materias.ico/$row.png'></a>
            <p class='texto'>$row</p>
            </div>";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado definiendo una variable con el valor que necesitas imprimir y poner la misma variable en el string? Además, no debes poner la etiqueta de PHP en el `echo`, pues puedes imprimir directamente la variable y no tendría caso hacerlo

Comment: @anythingg ya elimine lo que mencionaste pero sigue dando error en las comillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
...c.php?$_SESSION['Materia']
```

Estás dentro de un string, y la variable `$_SESSION` es un array, por ende te dará:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in...

Solo puedes poner variables completas, no índices en un string

```php
<?php
session_start();
$cp = $_SESSION['Materia'];
            echo
            "<div class='contenedor' id='uno'>
            <a href='c.php?{$cp}={$row}'><img class='icon' src='materias.ico/$row.png'></a>
            <p class='texto'>$row</p>
            </div>";
?>
```

Puedes poner las llaves para especificar que pondremos una variable en un punto específico, ya que sigue un número o letra será tomado como nombre de la variable

Es decir:

No es lo mismo hacer:

```php
echo "$holamundo";
```

Que:

```
echo "{$hola}mundo";
```

En el primer caso, será tomada la variable completa, y se imprimirá la variable `$holamundo`, en el segundo caso, se imprimirá la variable `$hola` y lo demás será un string

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```php
echo
    "<div class='contenedor' id='uno'>
    <a href='c.php?".$_SESSION['Materia']."'><img class='icon' src='materias.ico/$row.png'></a>
    <p class='texto'>$row</p>
    </div>";
```

Si la variable de sesión solo contiene un solo dato lo que debes es escapar con comilla, lo que no entiendo es porque le asignas un valor dentro del `href='c.php?{$cp}={$row}'`

Comment: Le asigno un valor dentro del href ya que necesito que al momento que le den clic a ese href mande a la variable sesion lo que se le indica, ya que todo eso esta dentro de un for each, pero tampoco puedo mandarlo por url porque me causa problema